# ElasticSearch on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to get ElasticSearch running in an Elastic Beanstalk environment. Using Docker image it's fairly straightforward to get one instance running in a load balanced environment. However, when I try to add more instances to the cluster, they fail to discover each other and every new one becomes a new_master.

My `Dockerfile` looks like following

```
FROM dockerfile/java:oracle-java8
RUN ... # Downloading and installing ElasticSearch
RUN /elasticsearch/bin/plugin install elasticsearch/elasticsearch-cloud-aws/2.5.0
VOLUME ["/data"]
ADD config/elasticsearch.yml /elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
WORKDIR /data
CMD ["/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch"]

EXPOSE 9200
```

And the configuration `config/elasticsearch.yml` looks like following:

```
cluster:
  name: elastic-env-dev
cloud:
  aws:
    region: ap-southeast-2
discovery:
  type: ec2
  ec2:
    tag:
      Name: elastic-env-dev
    ping_timeout: 120s
```

The name of the EB environment is `elastic-env-dev`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### It is possible to deploy ES on EBT, here is how

http://vladmiller.com/elasticsearch/aws/2015/12/08/deploy-elasticsearch-on-aws-elasticbeanstalk.html

---

At this point (November 14 2015), after spend some good amount of time I'll say that **it's not possible** to make ES cluster works on EB.

**Problem #1** is that you have to map docker port to host machine as if you would do

```
docker run -p 9300:9300 ...
```

This could be very easily solved if you add post appdeploy hook via [.ebextensions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html) which will setup iptables port forwarding

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_setup_iptables.sh":
    mode: "0755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/bin/sh
      iptables-save | grep -v added_by_ebextension | iptables-restore

      DOCKER_IP=$(docker inspect `cat /etc/elasticbeanstalk/.aws_beanstalk.current-container-id` | jq -r .[0].NetworkSettings.IPAddress)
      iptables -t nat -A DOCKER -p tcp --dport 9300:9400 -j DNAT --to-destination ${DOCKER_IP} -m comment --comment added_by_ebextension

      service iptables save
```

**Problem #2** you need to adjust security group, make sure you allow TCP 9300-9400 and ICMP traffic between nodes in SG.

**Problem #3** use aws-ec2 discovery plugin and limit it to your SG, therefore no other machines get's discovered

```
// elasticsearch.yml

cloud.aws:
  access_key: YYYYYYYYY
  secret_key: XXXXXXXXX
  region: us-east-1

discovery.type: ec2
discovery.ec2.ping_timeout: 30s
discovery.ec2.tag.Name: [ENVIRONMENT_NAME]
discovery.ec2.host_type: private_dns
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
```

**Problem #4, unsolved** is that each ES node will bind to internal docker IP address, which is something like **172.17.0.3**, however your host private IP is different. Therefore when nodes will discover each other and start to communicate they will report wrong IP address to others.

```
[2015-11-13 21:50:58,542][TRACE][discovery.zen.ping.unicast] [86ac0ad55d5b] [2] received response from {#zen_unicast_21_#cloud-i-8c317a3b-0#}{10.165.71.177}{ip-10-165-71-177.ec2.internal/10.165.71.177:9300}: [ping_response{node [{86ac0ad55d5b}{U3PF5qOaQCucpK3JfZ3ARA}{172.17.0.3}{172.17.0.3:9300}], id[5], master [null], hasJoinedOnce [false], cluster_name[es-staging]}, ping_response{node [{86ac0ad55d5b}{U3PF5qOaQCucpK3JfZ3ARA}{172.17.0.3}{172.17.0.3:9300}], id[7], master [null], hasJoinedOnce [false], cluster_name[es-staging]}, ping_response{node [{86ac0ad55d5b}{U3PF5qOaQCucpK3JfZ3ARA}{172.17.0.3}{172.17.0.3:9300}], id[9], master [null], hasJoinedOnce [false], cluster_name[es-staging]}, ping_response{node [{86ac0ad55d5b}{U3PF5qOaQCucpK3JfZ3ARA}{172.17.0.3}{172.17.0.3:9300}], id[11], master [null], hasJoinedOnce [false], cluster_name[es-staging]}, ping_response{node [{89764d1bb185}{yVRC-HmIQoayIuWfi6a09g}{172.17.0.3}{172.17.0.3:9300}], id[30], master [{89764d1bb185}{yVRC-HmIQoayIuWfi6a09g}{172.17.0.3}{172.17.0.3:9300}], hasJoinedOnce [true], cluster_name[es-staging]}]
```

You can see that node discovered on **ip-10-165-71-177.ec2.internal/10.165.71.177:9300**, however that node responded that it's IP is **172.17.0.3** thus first node instead of connection to EC2 private IP will try to connect to internal Docker IP

```
[2015-11-13 21:51:00,037][TRACE][discovery.ec2 ] [86ac0ad55d5b] full ping responses:
--> ping_response{node [{89764d1bb185}{yVRC-HmIQoayIuWfi6a09g}{172.17.0.3}{172.17.0.3:9300}], id[30], master [{89764d1bb185}{yVRC-HmIQoayIuWfi6a09g}{172.17.0.3}{172.17.0.3:9300}], hasJoinedOnce [true], cluster_name[es-staging]}
[2015-11-13 21:51:00,041][DEBUG][discovery.ec2 ] [86ac0ad55d5b] filtered ping responses: (filter_client[true], filter_data[false])
--> ping_response{node [{89764d1bb185}{yVRC-HmIQoayIuWfi6a09g}{172.17.0.3}{172.17.0.3:9300}], id[30], master [{89764d1bb185}{yVRC-HmIQoayIuWfi6a09g}{172.17.0.3}{172.17.0.3:9300}], hasJoinedOnce [true], cluster_name[es-staging]}
```

We need to somehow make ES to bind to host's IP address or ignore those docker IP addresses and continue on discovered IP.

---

**UPDATE 1** I suspect that you can deploy ES to EB without Docker, however I have not tried this option yet.

---

**UPDATE 2** I was able to make nodes discover each other and try to communicate, however now it has a [different issue](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/invalid-internal-transport-message-format-ff-f4-ff-fd/34586)

---

**UPDATE 3** Here is the story and sample code on how to achieve desired effect http://vladmiller.com/elasticsearch/aws/2015/12/08/deploy-elasticsearch-on-aws-elasticbeanstalk.html

Comment: The link to vladmiller.com is broken.  Has the blog been rehosted somewhere?

Comment: Vlad has the code on [his Github](https://github.com/vladmiller/elasticsearch-beanstalk), and the blog can be accessed [through archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20160304104122/http://vladmiller.com/elasticsearch/aws/2015/12/08/deploy-elasticsearch-on-aws-elasticbeanstalk.html)

Answer (score 4):

1) Check your instance security groups, in order for ES instances to talk to each other they must use port 9300

2) AWS does not allow multicast. you must disable multicast in the elasticsearch config

add this line to the config on each ES config

```
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
```

if that doesn't work, try adding unicast config

```
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: loadbalancer.address
```

3) remember the security groups on instances must allow 9300 from the ELB

```
Custom TCP Rule  TCP  9300 amazon-elb/sg-123456ed (amazon-elb-sg)
```

4) use telnet to check comm between the ES instances by using

```
telnet ip_address 9300
```

Comment: I forgot you must also expose port 9300 on the docker file

Comment: Still in the dark here. Cannot `telnet` to anything, even to the same machine, unless I use the IP from `sudo docker inspect ... | grep IP`. Random guess, can it be caused by not mapped IPv4? The one suspicious line is `bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/172.17.0.5:9300]}`

Comment: are security groups allowing port 9300?

also add this to the config:
      network.host: _ec2:privateIpv4_

Comment: @RăzvanPetruescu you cannot connect to local instance IP because port from docker isn't mapped to host machine. And AWS runs one container per VPS. You can create appdeploy post hook which will map IP via iptables, however there is still another issue which I don't know how to solve. You can read about it here https://discuss.elastic.co/t/deploy-es-to-aws-beanstalk/34567